# Create a connection into 2 databases from java application

Tags: java, sql-server, database, connection

I have code of Connection class, where it gets a connection only from one database. Look at the DBConnection.java below

```
package eksim.db.sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBConnection {

    public Connection conn=null;
    private static DBConnection dbConn=null;
    static final String DB_URL=
            "jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.47\\test;databaseName=a;";
    static final String DB_USER="sa";
    static final String DB_PASS="123";




    public DBConnection(){
         if(conn==null){
             try{
                 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
                 conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
             }
             catch(Exception ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
    }





    public static  DBConnection getInstance(){
        DBConnection conn=null;
        if(dbConn==null){
            System.out.println("New");
            dbConn=new DBConnection();
            conn=dbConn;
        } else{
            conn=dbConn;
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public Connection getCon() throws SQLException{
        return this.conn;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to create another connection into the different database. Could anyone give me suggestion to modify this code in order to get the result of Connection into 2 database? thanks for any reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DBConnection {

public Connection conn=null;
private static DBConnection dbConn=null;
static final String DB_URL=
        "jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.47\\test;databaseName=a;";
static final String DB_USER="sa";
static final String DB_PASS="123";


 public Connection secCon=null;
static final String DB_URL_SECOND= // URL

static final String DB_USER_SECOND=""; // user name
static final String DB_PASS_SECOND="123";




public DBConnection(){
     if(conn==null){
         try{
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
             conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
             secCon=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_SECOND, DB_USER_SECOND, DB_PASS_SECOND);
         }
         catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide some means to identify different connections, but also to configure those connections.

You could provide a `newInstance` method, passing it a name, which is used to identify the connection and the connection properties required to create that connection.

Then, when ever you wanted to get a reference to the connection, you could simply use `getInstance(name)`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DBConnection {

    public Connection conn = null;

    private static Map<String, DBConnection> mapInstances = new HashMap<String, DBConnection>(25);

    private String dbURL;
    private String dbUser;
    private String dbPassword;

    private DBConnection(String dbURL, String dbUser, String dbPassword) {
        this.dbPassword = dbPassword;
        this.dbURL = dbURL;
        this.dbUser = dbUser;
    }

    public synchronized static DBConnection newInstance(String name, String dbURL, String dbUser, String dbPassword) {
        DBConnection con = new DBConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);
        mapInstances.put(name, con);
        return con;
    }

    public synchronized static DBConnection getInstance(String name) {
        return mapInstances.get(name);
    }

    public synchronized Connection getCon() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return this.conn;
    }

}
```

For example...

```
DBConnection db1 = DBConnection.newInstance("db1", ....);
DBConnection db2 = DBConnection.newInstance("db2", ....);
```

And when you want to access the connection again...

```
DBConnection db1 = DBConnection.getInstance("db1");
DBConnection db2 = DBConnection.getInstance("db2");
```

Comment: think it would be best if you have `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap` , its better while working with threads which is pretty much all the time :)

Comment: @AnanthaSharma It's certainly a valid point, but the two instance methods are `synchronized`